# Is this question on apple numbers spreadsheet software on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions like these on topic? I look at the excel tag since it's analagous, and it says

> Only for questions on complex formula development or VBA programming. Show your data together with the expected results and your current effort to resolve the problem. General help regarding MS Excel for single worksheet functions is available at Super User.

I don't think this question falls into that category (analogously applied to the apple app)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735512/apple-numbers-sum-all-rows-below-cell-but-not-the-summary-row-dynamically

Comment: Also, I agree that the question is off-topic (not programming related) and would be better suited on Super User or Ask Different.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Add that as an answer?

Comment: If you edit the question to be more about whether the question is off-topic, instead of how to close it, then this question will probably be reopened. Give me a ping if this question does get reopened, and I'll answer it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I did edit it before it was closed, maybe I didn't edit it enough? I edited it further though

Comment: @Daenyth Are you *really* unsure if this question is on topic?  Editing the question to ask a question you already know the answer to, just so that it's no longer a duplicate, isn't particularly productive for anyone.

Comment: @Servy It was my original intent at the time I asked it, I just didn't express it well. The VTC comment was intended to be an aside since normally I'd just cast a vote and leave it to the rest of the community to see if it's substantiated.

Comment: @Daenyth So you feel sufficiently confident that the question should be closed as to cast a close vote, and yet you're asking us if it should be closed?  If you really don't know if it should be closed, then you shouldn't be (trying to) cast a close vote, you should be asking first.  If you're sufficiently confident that the question merits closure, then you shouldn't need to be asking if it merits closure.

Comment: \*[Apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.). \*[Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_(spreadsheet)). \*[Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel).

Answer (score 2):

That question is definitely off-topic because it's not about programming at all.  It's not actually about using any code to interact with the spreadsheet software.  It's literally asking how to better use the software.  It's not even asking *why* (from a programming perspective), that error exists.  Just [application X] isn't working in this corner case.  How do I better operate [application X].

From the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming.

This kind of question is better suited on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (or in this case [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), the Apple site, since this is an Apple application).